# 'variable' is not declared error for ascx web control

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, web-controls, ascx

I've two User Control, in both control I've in ascx some Javascript that call some code method.
The controls are practically identical but for the first (UploadPhotoHTML5.ascx) I've some errors like 'variable' is not declared, for the second (UploadPhotoSWF.ascx.vb) the Javascript code don't alert me with anyu errors.
(**UploadPhotoHTML5.ascx with errors highlighted**)
[image]
(**UploadPhotoSWF.ascx.vb without errors**)
[image]
Full code is browsable here: https://github.com/Scippy/Property-Agent/tree/DNN9-Update/Controls
I've tried to clean obj directory and rebuild but nothing.
I'm not sure what's causing this...any ideas to fix it?

Comment: Those are not variables, they are functions.  Are they public in the code-behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'is Visual Studio Issue, the same project opened with Visual Studio 2019 work perfectly, on the Visual Studio 2017 the issue is still there!

Comment: I had to restart Visual Studio to make it work.